# Pseudo-code from some MIT courseware

Tags: pseudocode

I've never had much need for writing large quantities of formal pseudo-code but the need has arisen, so I thought I'd pick some standards in order to stay consistent across code.

To that effect I picked up some "iTunes U" courseware videos, amongst other things the [6.046J / 18.410J Introduction to Algorithms (SMA 5503)](http://ocw.mit.edu/OcwWeb/Electrical-Engineering-and-Computer-Science/6-046JFall-2005/CourseHome/).

In the very first lecture video, the lecturer writes Insertion Sort on the blackboard, and he writes this:

```
Insertion-Sort(A, N) // Sorts A[1..n]
  for j ← 2 to n
    do key ← A[j]
      i ← j-1
      while i > 0 and A[i] > key
        do A[i+1] ← A[i]
          i ← i-1
      A[i+1] ← key
```

So, my questions:

- Why `i ← j-1` when `A[i+1] = key`? That is, why `←` in some cases, and `=` in another? Note that in the above code, the `←` is used for the latter too, but in the handouts, available on the web, `=` is used, is this simply a typo? (I assume so)
- More important, why `do key ← A[j]` when `i ← j-1`? What is so special that it requires a `do` command like that, and an indentation?

In other words, why isn't the above pseudo-code written like this (with my highlights):

```
Insertion-Sort(A, N) // Sorts A[1..n]
  for j ← 2 to n
    key ← A[j]                  <-- lost the do here
    i ← j-1                     <-- no indentation
    while i > 0 and A[i] > key
      A[i+1] ← A[i]             <-- lost the do here
      i ← i-1                   <-- no indentation
    A[i+1] ← key
```

Final question: Does anyone have a *code standard* for pseudo-code handy somewhere? My main goal is consistency, so that I only have to "teach" the recipients once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Structured English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_English) is a 'standardised' pseudo-code language.

Answer (score 0):

the arrow serve as = in normal code.

equal sign in pseudo serve as == in normal code

so `j <- 1` mean `j = 1`

and `j = 1`   mean `if( j == 1)`